# Using cabal to compile but not run the test suite?

Tags: haskell, cabal

`cabal test` will compile the test suite executable and then run it. However, it removes the console colouring (because it logs the result). I'd like to use cabal to build the executable and then run it from a script, but I can't figure out how to just build the executable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you `cabal configure --enable-tests`, then `cabal build` will build not just the library/executables, but also the test suites. You can also build individual test suites by name, saying `cabal build name-of-test-suite`.

You can run them manually from the appropriate subdirectories under `dist/build` if you don't want to use `cabal test`.

Furthermore, if it's e.g. a `tasty` test suite, you may be able to get color output by saying something like

```
cabal test --show-details=always --test-option=--color --test-option=always
```

You can also try `--show-details=streaming`. I don't know how robust this is, though, and whether it works may also depend on the platform you are on.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for. A minor correction: it should be --test-option=always at the end.