# Create and run a minimal test suite in Haskell using Hunit only

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, cabal, hunit

I'm relatively new to Haskell, so apologies in advance if my terminology is not quite correct.

I would like to implement some plain unit test for a very simple project, managed through `cabal`. I noticed [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874601/how-to-use-hunit-and-cabal-to-do-automated-testing), but it didn't really help. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175592/using-cabal-to-compile-but-not-run-the-test-suite) didn't either (and it mentions `tasty`, see below).

I *think* I can accomplish this by using only `HUnit` - however, I admit I am a bit confused by all other "things" that guides on the net talk about:

- I don't quite appreciate [the difference between the interfaces](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-package.html?highlight=test#pkg-field-test-suite-type) `exitcode-stdio-1.0` and `detailed-0.9`
- I am not sure about the differences (or mid- and long-terms) implication of using `HUnit` or `Quickcheck` or others?
- What's the role of `tasty` that the HUnit guide mentions.

So, I tried to leave all "additional" packages out of the equation and everything else as "default" as much as I could aside and did the following:

```bash
$ mkdir example ; mkdir example/test
$ cd example
$ cabal init
```

Then edited `example.cabal` and added this section:

```hs
Test-Suite test-example
    type:             exitcode-stdio-1.0
    hs-source-dirs:   test, app
    main-is:          Main.hs
    build-depends:    base >=4.15.1.0,
                      HUnit
    default-language: Haskell2010
```

Then I created `test/Main.hs` with this content:

```hs
module Main where

import Test.HUnit

tests = TestList [
    TestLabel "test2"
        (TestCase $ assertBool "Why is this not running," False)
                 ]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    runTestTT tests
    return ()
```

Finally, I tried to run the whole lot:

```bash
$ cabal configure --enable-tests && cabal build && cabal test
Up to date
Build profile: -w ghc-9.2.4 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - example-0.1.0.0 (test:test-example) (additional components to build)
Preprocessing test suite 'test-example' for example-0.1.0.0..
Building test suite 'test-example' for example-0.1.0.0..
Build profile: -w ghc-9.2.4 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - example-0.1.0.0 (test:test-example) (ephemeral targets)
Preprocessing test suite 'test-example' for example-0.1.0.0..
Building test suite 'test-example' for example-0.1.0.0..
Running 1 test suites...
Test suite test-example: RUNNING...
Test suite test-example: PASS
Test suite logged to:
/home/jir/workinprogress/haskell/example/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-9.2.4/example-0.1.0.0/t/test-example/test/example-0.1.0.0-test-example.log
1 of 1 test suites (1 of 1 test cases) passed.
```

And the output is not what I expected.
I'm clearly doing something fundamentally wrong, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the `exitcode-stdio-1.0` test type to recognize a failed suite, you need to arrange for your test suite's `main` function to exit with failure in case there are any test failures.  Fortunately, there's a `runTestTTAndExit` function to handle this, so if you replace your `main` with:

```
main = runTestTTAndExit tests
```

it should work fine.

Comment: And sure enough, they failed. Thanks! I can't fathom why `runTestTTAndExit` is not even mentioned in the official docs. Also, what would be the point of `runTestTT` then?

Comment: @Jir `runTestTT` produces more readable output than `runTestTTAndExit` when executed inside ghci.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @glyn! I wasn't hoping anyone would answer at this point.